# Spring Boot JpaRepository integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I need to extend my unit tests with some integration tests.

I have some JpaRepository Objects to retrieve data from a SQL Server DB and process them. This must be integrated in some integration tests.

I wrote a testclass which calls the REST controller.
The testclass is annotated with:

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.data.repository")
@EntityScan("com.data.model")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

But when I run the tests I get errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in com.data.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyControllerTest: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5dc59c57' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5dc59c57': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5dc59c57': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

I need for this kind of testing the integration with the database. It is not enough to use a Mock DB or something like that.
How can I do that?

Full stack trace of the logged message:

```
    "thread": "main",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "loggerName": "org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager",
    "message": "Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@a8c2b080] to prepare test instance [com.test.MyControllerTest@5192c2be]",
    "thrown": {
        "commonElementCount": 0,
        "localizedMessage": "Failed to load ApplicationContext",
        "message": "Failed to load ApplicationContext",
        "name": "java.lang.IllegalStateException",
        "cause": {
            "commonElementCount": 85,
            "localizedMessage": "Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in com.data.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5d837786' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
            "message": "Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in com.data.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5d837786' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
            "name": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",
            "cause": {
                "commonElementCount": 85,
                "localizedMessage": "Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
                "message": "Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
                "name": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",
                "cause": {
                    "commonElementCount": 85,
                    "localizedMessage": "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
                    "message": "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available",
                    "name": "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException",
                    "extendedStackTrace": "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$518/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n"
                },
                "extendedStackTrace": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$518/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$518/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\t... 85 more\n"
            },
            "extendedStackTrace": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in com.data.repository.MyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5d837786' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$518/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d837786': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$518/0x0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]\n\tat  85 more\n"
    }
```

Comment: Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@EntityScan` and `@ExtendsWith` re-run. Make sure that you have a test database you can connect to or use something like TestContainers to start a dockerized one for the tests. Without a DB it won't start. By default the test will use an H2 database (in-memory) but you changed that with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`

Comment: Removing this annotations does not change anything :-( I have a test database available, no docker is involved. Any I really need to connect to this database, temporary H2 database is not possible.

Comment: Then put the proper configuiration in the `application.properties` so it can connect.

Comment: Properties are present in test/resources/application.yml. This database is accessible. When I put this configuration to main I can run the project without tests, so I can see, that connection is working

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace/error you get?

Comment: I added stack trace above.

Comment: Hmm that is in JSON, don't you have it from the console? The one in JSON seems cut off as well.

Comment: Yes, console output is converted to Json in my environment to fullfill logging requirements. I added all to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/LVfiTqyb Line 25 you will see the stack trace

Comment: If your test hits the controller, it looks like its a full integration test, so your test class should be annotated with SpringBootTest. In which package is your SpringBootApplication annotated class? I sense that something is off with your package structure.

Comment: Also if this is a full interation test you should use `@SpringBootTest` currently you are only testing the JPA stuff but you mention a controller. The combination controller and `@DataJpaTest` is weird.